# can I gain ownership of my migrated question?

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, migration

can I gain somehow ownership of my question that was migrated from [Web Application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10281/audio-streaming-that-cannot-be-saved-closed)W?

here is the [migrated question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6663/audio-streaming-that-cannot-be-saved)

Comment: Are you using the same OpenID here as you are on Web Applications?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: yes, I'm but registered here after the question was migrated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry -- you now have access to it, I manually kicked off the auto-association and it got picked up.

There are some problems with our migrated question association code and it is being refactored.

Comment: thank you for that